# How to send a default string together with the form?

Tags: php, database, record

```
<?php

require_once 'connection.php';

$slug = '';

if(isset($_POST["create"])){ 

  $slug = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', '-', trim(strtolower($_POST["title"])));

  $query = "SELECT slug_url FROM bn_publicacao WHERE slug_url LIKE '$slug%'";

  $statement = $conn->prepare($query); 

  if($statement->execute()){

    $total_row = $statement->rowCount();

    if($total_row > 0){

      $result = $statement->fetchAll();

      foreach($result as $row){

      $data[] = $row['slug_url'];

      }

      if(in_array($slug, $data)){

        $count = 0;
        while( in_array( ($slug . '-' . ++$count ), $data) );
        $slug = $slug . '-' . $count;

      }

    }

  }

  $insert_data = array(

    ':title'      => $_POST['title'],
    ':descricao'  => $_POST['descricao'],
    ':capa'       => $_POST['capa'],
    ':alt'        => $_POST['alt'],
    ':keywords'   => $_POST['keywords'],
    ':categoria'  => $_POST['categoria'],
    ':slug_url'   => $slug,
    ':slug_link'  => $slug,
    ':entry_type' => $_POST['entry_type'],

  );

  $query = "INSERT INTO bn_publicacao (title, descricao, capa, alt, keywords, categoria, slug_url, slug_link, entry_type) VALUES (:title, :descricao, :capa, :alt, :keywords, :categoria, :slug_url, :slug_link, :entry_type)";
  $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
  $statement->execute($insert_data);    
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Form</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  

    <style>
      .box
      {
       max-width:600px;
       width:100%;
       margin: 0 auto;;
      }
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container box">

    <br />
    <h3 align="center">Gravar post</h3>
    <br />

      <form method="post">

        <div class="form-group">

          <label>Title</label>
          <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control mb-3" required />

          <label>Descicao</label>
          <input type="text" name="descricao" class="form-control mb-3" required />

          <label>Capa</label>
          <input type="text" name="capa" class="form-control mb-3" required />

          <label>Alt</label>
          <input type="text" name="alt" class="form-control mb-3" required />

          <label>Keywords</label>
          <input type="text" name="keywords" class="form-control mb-3" required />

          <label>Categoria</label>
          <input type="text" name="categoria" class="form-control mb-3" required />

          <label>Entry_type</label>
          <input type="text" name="entry_type" class="form-control mb-3" required />

        </div>

        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="create" class="btn btn-info" value="Enviar" />
        </div>
        <br />

        <h4>Generated Slug - <?php echo $slug; ?></h4>

      </form>

    </div>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

The `input`"title" automatically generate a slug that will be send to the columns `slug_url` and `slug_link`, i need to send a default string together on the `slug_url`.

I want to add a default url on the slug gererated to the column `slug_url`.

Example:

I want to add this url as default on the slug generated "http://example.com/"

this-is-the-slug-gererated-to-the-column-slug-url

And this is how it should be send to my column `slug_url`:

http://example.com/this-is-the-slug-gererated-to-the-column-slug-url

Comment: Please include sample data showing what URL you are trying to send.

Comment: I'm not clear what your example is showing. Can you please clarify? Also that prepared statement is incorrect usage. Values should be put into the query as placeholders and then bound in the `execute` or using `bindparam`. (actually just the `SELECT` one the `insert` is correct.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Please check my question, i edited.

Comment: @user3783243 Check my question again. Please let me know if you did not understand yet.

Comment: Can you just do something like this? `$slug = "https://example.com/".preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', '-', trim(strtolower($_POST["title"])));`

Comment: @LongKim Yes but as i said i need to add the `https://example.com/` only to the column `slug_url`. Do you know how can i do it?

Comment: yes you can add something like this `':slug_url'   => "https://example.com/".$slug,`

Comment: @Susi no worries, Can i add my answer now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add something like this

`':slug_url' => "https://example.com/".$slug,`

Answer (score 1):

Very simple, just change this part of the code:

```
$insert_data = array(

    ':title'      => $_POST['title'],
    ':descricao'  => $_POST['descricao'],
    ':capa'       => $_POST['capa'],
    ':alt'        => $_POST['alt'],
    ':keywords'   => $_POST['keywords'],
    ':categoria'  => $_POST['categoria'],
    ':slug_url'   => "https://example.com/$slug",
    ':slug_link'  => $slug,
    ':entry_type' => $_POST['entry_type'],

  );
```

Notice I just changed the line setting the :slug_url column